# Windows 8. Hosts file doesn't work

Tags: dns, hosts-file, windows-8-preview

I am using Windows 8 developer preview (x64) for testing purposes. I want to access some local network resource by DNS. So, I've added next line to my hosts file (`%sindir%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`):

```
169.254.1.20       host.local
```

but when I'am trying to ping host.local I get the following error

```
Ping request could not find host unsecure.local. Please check the name and try a
gain.
```

Trying to open it from IE also displays a connection error (local proxy not needed and turned off).

but the output of

```
C:\Users\moonorg>ipconfig /displaydns
```

displayed my host:

```
Windows IP Configuration

61.2.254.169.in-addr.arpa
----------------------------------------
Name does not exist.


20.1.254.169.in-addr.arpa
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : 20.1.254.169.in-addr.arpa.
Record Type . . . . . : 12
Time To Live  . . . . : 86400
Data Length . . . . . : 8
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
PTR Record  . . . . . : host.local


189.0.254.169.in-addr.arpa
----------------------------------------
Name does not exist.


host.local
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : host.local
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 86400
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
A (Host) Record . . . : 169.254.1.20


host.local
----------------------------------------
No records of type AAAA
```

So, it's looks like DNS resolving problem. How do I make my hosts file work?

**UPD:**
Ping by IP works fine, so it's kind of name resolving problem.

Comment: Why are you using auto-assigned IPs (169.254.x.x)?  They are often blocked from routing.  Also, HOSTS file != DNS

Comment: Windows 8 is on virtual machine with bridged network adapter (Virtual Box). Auto assigned IP - IP of my host machine, where my server hosted. I know, this is not good for alltime, but good enough for testing purposes. I'am think this is not routing trouble. Ping can't resolve name to IP.

Comment: Routing directs IP traffic, no route = no ping.

Comment: [Please ensure that the names and addresses given in your question are the ones that you actually used.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-obscure-your-dns-data.html)

Comment: Names and IP's are real. Everything is locally, so I used test names.

Comment: That's difficult to believe, given that in one place in your question you write one name and in another place you write a different one.

Comment: when you ping host.local, do you really get exactly "Ping request could not find host unsecure.local. Please check the name and try a
gain." returned? Do you have any idea why it would say unsecure.local if you're pinging host.local?

Comment: I would first use some other DNS server to make sure it's not your dns server specific issue. Also I would read up on [this](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hostswin8.htm)

Comment: Take a look at this, if you haven't already.  

http://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot

Answer (score -1):

Try using localhost instead of host.local and reboot your computer after every change to the hosts file. Also, remember to keep a backup.

Comment: Also, do an ipconfig /flushdns to clear DNS cache!